# Does React batch props updates in some cases?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm curious whether React batches updates to props in some rare cases? There is no mention of this in the docs, but I couldn't come up with any other explanation of the following situation.

I have an equivalent to the following code:

```
// Connected component
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        shouldDisplayError: false,
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log("componentDidUpdate: " + this.props.dataState);
        if (
            prevProps.dataState === "FETCHING" &&
            this.props.dataState === "FETCH_FAILED"
        ) {
            this.setState(() => ({ shouldDisplayError: true }));
        }
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.shouldDisplayError && <p>Awesome error message!</p>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const dataState = getMyDataStateFromState(state);
    // dataState can be "NOT_INITIALIZED" (default), "FETCHING", "FETCH_SUCCEEDED" or "FETCH_FAILED"
    console.log("mapStateToProps: " + dataState);
    return {
        dataState,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);

// A thunk triggered by a click in another component:
export async const myThunk = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCHING_DATA" });
    let result;
    try {
        result = await API.getData(); // an error thrown immediately inside of here
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCHING_DATA_FAILED" });
        return;
    }
    dispatch({type: "FETCHING_DATA_SUCCEEDED", data: result.data});
}

// Let's say this is the API:
export const API = {
    getData: () => {
        console.log("> api call here <");
        throw "Some error";  // in a real API module, there's a check that would throw in some cases - this is the equivalent for the unhappy path observed
        // here would be the fetch call
    },
}
```

What I would *expect to see* in the console *after triggering the API call* (*which immediately fails*), is the following:

```
mapStateToProps: FETCHING
componentDidUpdate: FETCHING
> api call here <
mapStateToProps: FETCH_FAILED
componentDidUpdate: FETCH_FAILED
```

However, I can see the following instead:

```
mapStateToProps: FETCHING
> api call here <
mapStateToProps: FETCH_FAILED
componentDidUpdate: FETCH_FAILED
```

So the `MyComponent` component never received the `"FETCHING"` `dataState`, although it has been seen in the `mapStateToProps` function. And thus never displayed the error message. Why? Is it because such fast updates to a component's `props` are batched by React (like calls to `this.setState()` in some cases)???

**Basically, the question is: If I dispatch two actions, really quickly after each other, triggering a component's props updates, does React batch them, effectively ignoring the first one?**

Comment: How you are triggering your API ? I mean where you are dispatching any action for fetching data ?

Comment: The `myThunk` thunk is dispatched from an `onClick` handler inside of another component.

Comment: I've added comments in the code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The first time, a component is rendered, componentDidUpdate is NOT called. Instead, componentDidMount is called. Log to console in componentDidMount as well to see the message.

Comment: No, actually in componentDidMount, I would see "NOT_INITIALIZED" as the dataState. The dataState lifecycle is NOT_INITIALIZED -> FETCHING -> FETCH_SUCCEEDED/FETCH_FAILED. Perhaps the question is not clear enough.